# Games in which one player acts first, followed by both players acting

Tags: reference-request, game-theory

Games in which one player acts first, followed by another player acting are referred to as [Stackelberg games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stackelberg_competition).

Does anyone know of a class of games where one player acts first, followed by **both** players acting simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stackelberg games are only a very small subset of [sequential games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_game) with perfect information, where players (not necessarily just two) move one after another.

The type of games you asked for -- one player acts first, followed by both players acting simultaneously -- falls under the set of sequential games with imperfect information. In the context of industrial organization, there are variants of "market entry games" such as the [Spence-Dixit entry-deterrence game](http://www.eco.uc3m.es/~mmachado/teaching/oi-i-mei/slides/3.6.SpenceDixitModel.pdf), that fit your description.